# Do I need to re-cache my object after I updated it in the memcache of Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I am currently using Google AppEngine(Java) to build a web site.

I created a bean to be cached in the memcache, when I retrieved it from the memecache and called some methods on it to update its status, do I need to re-cache it into memcache?

I guess that memcache used its reference, so I should not need to do it. But things turn out that I am not correct. I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to **re-cache** a bean, if you want to update it in the memcache.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html